# What is the probability of the length distribution for lines cutting through a circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I encountered this problem when I was reading a paper [1]. In it, the authors mentioned that if a circle has a radius of $c$, and a line cuts through it, then the probability for the length of this line lying between $\ell$ and $\ell+d\ell$ is
$\frac{\ell d\ell}{2c\sqrt{4c^2-\ell^2}}$ for $0<\ell<2c$ and $0$ for $2c<\ell$. I cannot understand how $\frac{\ell d\ell}{2c\sqrt{4c^2-\ell^2}}$ is derived. Could you please shed the light on me? Thanks!

[1] Cooper, M. G., B. B. Mikic, and M. M. Yovanovich. "Thermal contact conductance." International Journal of heat and mass transfer 12, no. 3 (1969): 279-300.

Comment: The distinction between "one" and letter "ell" is a little hard to make out for my tired old eyes.  May I recommend using (in MathJax) the symbol `\ell` for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many models for how a random line cutting through the circle can be chosen.

The one that the authors seem to be using is based on the idea that if I give you a point $P$ inside the circle, there is a unique line such that $P$ is its closest point to the center of the circle. (The line makes a chord inside the circle whose midpoint is $P$.) So the authors pick a uniformly random $r \in [0,c]$ and a uniformly random $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, then draw the line whose closest point to the center of the circle is $(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$.

To find the length of the chord, consider the right triangle through $O$ (the center of the circle), $P$ (the point above) and $X$ (one of the ends of the chord). Then $OX^2 = OP^2 + PX^2$ so $c^2 = r^2 + PX^2$ and $PX = \sqrt{c^2 - r^2}$. The length of the chord is twice $PX$: $2\sqrt{c^2-r^2}$.

To find the distribution of this quantity, we first find the CDF. The probability that the length of the chord is in $[0,\ell]$ is the probability that $2\sqrt{c^2-r^2} \le \ell$, or $r \ge \sqrt{c^2 - \ell^2/4}$. For $0<\ell<2c$, this describes an interval of length $c - \sqrt{c^2-\ell^2/4}$ for $r$, so the probability is $\frac{c - \sqrt{c^2-\ell^2/4}}{c} = 1 - \sqrt{1 - \frac{\ell^2}{4c^2}}$, because $r$ is uniformly chosen from $[0,c]$.

To find the probability that the length of the chord is in $[\ell,\ell+d\ell]$, we take the derivative of $1 - \sqrt{1 - \frac{\ell^2}{4c^2}}$, which gives us $-\frac1{2\sqrt{1 - \frac{\ell^2}{4c^2}}} \cdot -\frac{2\ell}{4c^2} = \frac{\ell}{2c\sqrt{4c^2-\ell^2}}$. After we multiply by $d\ell$, we get the answer in the paper.

---

Note, however, that different models for the random line will give different probabilities. My first guess about the random line was to pick two random points on the circle and draw a line through them. This gives the answer $\frac{2 d\ell}{\pi \sqrt{4c^2-\ell^2}}$, instead.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and the final comment. Actually, my first instinct is to pick a radius of the circle and draw a line perpendicular to it, then using the trigonometry to derive the probability of that line lying between $\ell$ and $\ell+d\ell$ seems to be $\frac{\sqrt{4c^2-\ell^2}d\ell}{2c\ell}$.

Comment: That can't be correct; the integral $\int_0^{2c}\frac{\sqrt{4c^2-\ell^2}d\ell}{2c\ell}$ doesn't converge. If you pick a radius of the circle, then pick a random *point* on that radius and draw a line perpendicular to the radius through that point, that's equivalent to the method in the paper, so it should give the same answer as that.

Comment: I see. I think I am wrong by using $\frac{\sqrt{c^2-\ell^2/4}}{l/2}$ to multiply $d\ell/2$ to get the differential length on the picked radius. This trigonometry is changing all the time with different picked points.

Comment: My general advice, if you are not used to working with these infinitesimal probabilities, is to do what I did in my answer: compute the CDF (the probability that the length is *at most* $\ell$) and then take the derivative with respect to $\ell$. This avoids the potential for many subtle mistakes.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!